# OnSaveInstance and onRestoreInstance do not work after rotating the screen

Tags: android

In the books of Android Essentials, they speak about onSaveInstance and onRestoreInstance to recuperate automaticaly the text that you put in a textfield on the screen after rotating the phone or tablet. While we know as you rotate the screen, the application will be destroyed and recreated.

The automaticaly restore doesn't work. While i tested the manualy saving the text in the methods onSaveInstance and set the text in the textfield in onRestoreInstance. That also doen't work!

Am i doing something wrong? I can't beleive that it isn't working while in these Essentials books they say it works for sure??

Comment: Can you paste your code please ?

Comment: Please post your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can also get data in onCreate(). Refer this for more [Developer Doc : Recreating an Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html)

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_state_changes);
        Log.i(TAG,"onCreate");
        final EditText textBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

        if(savedInstanceState != null){
              textBox.setText(savedInstanceState.getCharSequence("savedText"););
         }

    }
```

Comment: Ok Bharat, I will test it for sure. Thx for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This is the java code:

```
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.EditText;


    public class StateChangesActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "wimvangeyt.be.StateChanges";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_state_changes);
        Log.i(TAG,"onCreate");
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.state_changes, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();
        Log.i(TAG,"onStart");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        Log.i(TAG,"onResume");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        Log.i(TAG,"onPause");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop()
    {
        super.onStop();
        Log.i(TAG,"onStop");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onRestart()
    {
        super.onRestart();
        Log.i(TAG,"onRestart");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i(TAG,"onDestroy");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
    {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        Log.i(TAG,"onSaveInstanceState");

        final EditText textBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        CharSequence userText = textBox.getText();
        outState.putCharSequence("savedText", userText);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i(TAG,"onRestoreInstanceState");

        final EditText textBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        CharSequence userText =  savedInstanceState.getCharSequence("SavedText");
        textBox.setText(userText);
      }
    }
```

And This is the xml code:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".StateChangesActivity">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="142dp"
        android:saveEnabled="false"
        android:width="200dp"/>


    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Your problem is that you're putting "savedText" in onSaveInstanceState() and trying to get "SavedText" instead of "savedText" in onRestoreInstanceState().

Comment: And inside `onRestoreInstace()`, why r u calling `super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);` instead of `super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);`

Comment: Ow ok, i didn't see that first time. :s Thnx for pointing these out.

Comment: Ok I corrected the typo's and errors and it works fine now :D. Thanks a lot.